# How do you merge linked or appended objects into a single layer?

Tags: layers, append

After appending (not linking) a few objects from a different scene, the appended objects appear in all layers like this.

[image]

**How does one put the appended objects on a single layer to turn on/off**? After deleting the linked objects, the layers look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object can be present in more than one layer.

In the Relations section for the object you can select which ones to use.

[image]